# difficulty in posting videos on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an application in which i want to post videos on facebook.While i try to do that,i am getting this error:

```
Facebook Error: (#100) Requires extended permission: video_upload or Requires extended permission: publish_actions
```

This is the code:

```
mUploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                byte[] data = null;
                AssetFileDescriptor fileDesc = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
                R.raw.movie);
                String dataPath =  fileDesc.toString();
                String dataMsg = "Your video description here.";
                String dataName = "movie.mp4";
                Bundle param;
                AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                InputStream is ;
                try 
                {
                    is = fileDesc.createInputStream();

                //    is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
                    if(is != null)
                    data = readBytes(is);
                    param = new Bundle();
                    param.putString("message", dataMsg);
                    param.putString("filename", dataName);
                    param.putByteArray("video", data);
                    mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new SampleRequestListener(), null);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }
        });
```

Please tell me what is the problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is contained in the error message. It is a fairly clear error message I think.

In the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow for your app, you have not requested that the user grant you the `video_upload`, `publish_actions` or `publish_stream` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) - any of those three will allow video uploads, but the third is more wide-ranging and triggers a second page on the auth dialog.

Check whichever SDK you're using to see if it has a convenient wrapper to ask for additional permissions in the auth flow. In the regular Oauth flow, you just add the list of permissions needed as the `scope` parameter in your call to the [Oauth dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)

Comment: Can you please provide me some code so as to assist me how to do that